# insert multiple records into mysql in a single query from php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Can anyone help me with the code for the following problem.

```
Print "<th>Id no</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Maximum Marks</th><th>Marks Obtained</th></tr>"; 

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    Print "<tr><td>".$data['idno']." </td><td>".$data['name'] . " </td><td> <input type=text name=maxmarks></td><td> <input type=text name=obtmarks></td></tr>";
}

Print "</table><br><br><input type=submit value=submit></center>";
```

Actually the above code displays a table with four columns where the first 2 columns are retrieved from database and remaining 2 columns are textboxes...

User enters data and after clicking submit button the entire table has to be stored in database. Is it possible?

Comment: the entire table or the values that are entered by the user need to be updated?

Comment: ya entire table has to be inserted in database.. even the idnos nd names are to be inserted into another table in database along with the details entered in the textboxes..

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to insert multiple values separated by a comma in the database but you need to loop in your table and correctly format your query.

Example

```
INSERT INTO tablename (colA, colB, colC) VALUES (valueA, valueB, valueC),
                                                (valueD, valueE, valueF),
                                                (valueG, valueH, valueI)
```

Comment: I'm showing you how to insert multiple rows using single statement. This does not mean that there is only a max of 3. You can have thousands of it :)

Comment: hmm it becomes difficult to include all the rows in the query. can we place it a loop r wat..?

Comment: Of course you can. The reason why i showed it like that is because you can geneate the query by looping inthe table